# Making a field load automatically after a value gets inserted

Tags: onchange

I have a quantity field and customers can input a number and click a change button and then the my cart does all of the calculations. What I am looking for is how do I make that same field load and update all fields automatically on input??

Comment: call ajax function on click event of the button

Answer (score 0):

You can use blur event for your input to call the same function which you are calling on change button.  For instance, suppose you are calling the `Update()` function on change button in jQuery then now call it on input blur like this:

```
$('#inputID').blur(function(){
    Update();
});
```

Comment: $cartOutput .= '<td><div class="well-box-middle well-border-gradient align-center grid-10 tablet-grid-10"><form action="cart.php" method="post">
 <input name="quantity" class="text-input product-quantity dark-color light-bg" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1"/>
 <input name="adjustButton' . $item_id .'" type="submit" value="Change"/>
 <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '"/>
 </form></div></td>';

Comment: Hello, the above is my code for making the change happen.  How can I use the .blur function to change everything automatically?